# Web Service using MySQL and Hibernate Tutorial

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, hibernate, netbeans

Are there any good tutorials around which explain how to configure Hibernate with MySQL which can then be used to run a web-service? ideally so an android application can connect to it via http:// and bring back results.

I am preferably looking for a REST web service using the JavaEE framework.

Tutorials for either Eclipse or Netbeans are fine. I can't really find any good tutorials that explain this combination. Do I have to use my own initiative when looking at hibernate and web service tutorials separately? which is fine as long as I know i'm not missing something here..

Comment: You're missing a layer there.  Hibernate and mySQL do not combine to yield a web service.  What kind of web service?  REST, SOAP, XML-RPC, roll-your-own?  What web framework?  Spring, Jersey, full-stack JavaEE, Axis?  You can see, you will need to be more specific than "web service based on hibernate" to find a specific how-to :)

Comment: Ahh sorry. Preferably looking for a web service using REST and using the JavaEE framework. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should look at hibernate and web service tutorials separately.

Hibernate is a framework that focus on the data access layer,  [official page](http://www.hibernate.org/).

And eclipse comes with a wizard, that allows you to create web services from a class easily (just a few clicks)

I would start first researching on hibernate (first find out if that is what you wanna use...)

Then the web service.

Answer (score 0):

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html uses hibernate and mysql, not sure if it exposes it as web service. Note you can register MySQL, create a web app, then use the REST Services from Database file template to generate everything. I think you can choose Hibernate as your persistence provider there.